# how to modify the softlink created and checked in

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have created a softlink in `vob`

```
myscript.pl ->/usr2/myscript.pl
```

and checked in.

now i need to change the path of `softlink` like,

```
myscript.pl ->/usr2/john/myscript.pl
```

How to achieve this, in `cleartool`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in this [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21118146):

> **The only way to revise a VOB symbolic link to a relative path is to create a new symbolic link**:
>
> Note: **You cannot edit (revise) a VOB symbolic link if it has been created using an absolute path to utilize a relative path**.
>
> - Check out the directory
> - Remove the old VOB link using the `cleartool rmelem` command
> - Create a new link with the same name
>
> Example:

```
cleartool ln -slink -nc ../../same_file_name.txt
Check in the directory
```

> Notes:
>
> - It is recommended that you **use relative VOB symbolic links** instead of absolute symbolic links.
>     The absolute VOB symbolic link requires you to use absolute path names from the view-tag level, for example, `\view-tag\VOB-tag\filename`.
>     Hence, they are valid only in the view in which they were created.
> - Symbolic links that point to files outside the ClearCase MVFS are not supported by the Windows operating system (as opposed to the UNIX and Linux operating systems), and must be created with relative paths as opposed to absolute paths.
>     Although the [`cleartool ln` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21260645) will create the link, the link will not appear in a standard directory listing; it will only be displayed by the cleartool ls command.
>     This is true for all symbolic links that do not point to a valid MVFS path name.